# How to know how much temp table space required for expdp job?

Tags: oracle, tablespace, expdp

```
expdp $DBNAME directory=ar_exp content=data_only dumpfile=${tablename}.dmp logfile=${tablename}.log tables=$tablename query=$SCHNAME.$tablename:'"where substr('$fieldname',1,5) in('$cpidlst')"'
```

Here this operation takes temp tablespace, but how much temp tablespace will be required how to calculate?

Comment: I didn't get answer yet and you people marked this as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the link to the estimate answer, here is a script we use to find out how much temp is being used.  You have to find the SID of your expdp session and then join it to the WHERE clause.

```
select
  s.sid,
  s.serial#,
  p.spid "OS SID",
  s.sql_hash_value "HASH VALUE",
  s.username "ORA USER",
  s.status,
  s.osuser "OS USER",
  s.machine,
  s.terminal,
  s.type,
  s.program,
  s.logon_time,
  s.last_call_et,
  su.contents, 
  ROUND(((su.blocks*param.value)/1024/1024),2) "MB",
  tablespace,
  s.sql_id
FROM 
  v$session s, v$sort_usage su, v$process p, v$parameter param
WHERE 
  param.name  = 'db_block_size' and
  su.session_addr = s.saddr and
  p.addr = s.paddr
ORDER BY 
  su.blocks DESC;
```

Once you find the SID of your session:

> 1. Join it to V$SQL_TEXT and get the SQL_TEXT
> 2. Find out how to create PLAN_TABLE
> 3. Run "explain plan into plan_table for" the SQL_TEXT you found in step 1
> 4. Select TEMP_SPACE from PLAN_TABLE;

This should give you an estimate; however I have never found the estimate to be accurate.  The best way is to watch the session running, then use script above repeatedly if you have to.

Comment: I want to know how much will be required based on where condition?

Comment: I will update the answer now...